# Baby's name and as in someone/something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, idioms-in-context

I'm watching the TV show Friends and in the second episode heroes discuss the baby's name and here's the dialog:

```
 - How's about the baby's name?
 - Marlon or Minnie if it's a girl.
 - As in mouse?
 - As in my grandmother.
```

What do they mean by **as in mouse/grandmother**? They mean that the baby is named after her grandmother or mouse? I've just looked for the information about it on the Internet and found nothing.

Comment: The first speaker asks "Do you mean Minnie like [the character] Minnie Mouse?". The second speaker means "No, I'm suggesting Minnie because it is/was my grandmother's name."

Comment: Yeah, I see about the character, but what I'm asking about is **as in** construction. Can I use it if I mean to say that someone is named after someone else? For instance, my baby's name is as in my father. Is it okay?

Comment: No, it isn't.  _As in_ means _as in the phrase_; it's a way of asking in what sense someone has used a word that has more than one meaning (or, in this case, a name that has different associations for different people). The second speaker is just being humorous when they repeat 'as in' instead of explaining the reason literally.

Comment: You have to mention the name. My baby's name is Donald, as in the duck (not the President).

Comment: The relatively informal construction ***X as in Y*** only normally occurs in "disambiguating" contexts, where it basically means *Although **X** may have various different meanings, the **specific** one I'm talking about is **the one particularly associated with Y***.

Comment: Thank you all, I got the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as in** signals an example of something in English when a statement is ambiguous.

Person 1:  What about Marlon?
Person 2:  As in Marlon Brando? [For example, Marlon Brando}
Person 3: For example, like my grandfather. [As in my grandfather].

**as in** or **like in** are used to clarify a context in conversation, usually though as in can be used in writing also.

It can be used **in any context** where there is ambiguity.

Person 1: Let's leave it!
Person 2: Leave it **as in** drop it? [drop a subject or matter]
Person 1: Yes, let's forget it.